# java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException when reading a stream

Tags: scala, utf-8, stream, decoding, utf-16

I use the following code to read data. It throws java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException. 
The file I can open normally, but it does include non-ascii chars. Anyway I can fix this problem?

```
  Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines foreach { line =>
    // store items on the fly
    lineParser(line.trim) match {
      case None => // no-op
      case Some(pair) => // some-op
    }   
  }   
  stream.close()
```

The stream construction code is here:

```
def getStream(path: String) = {
  if (!fileExists(path)) {
    None
  } else {
    val fileURL = new URL(path)
    val urlConnection = fileURL.openConnection
    Some(urlConnection.getInputStream())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `Source.fromInputStream(stream)(io.Codec("UTF-8"))` or whatever charset you need.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The problem now is, I get "?" instead of diacritics :/

Answer (score 5):

Jean-Laurent is likely completely right that Stream.fromInputStream is using an encoding that doesn't match your stream—likely the platform default, i.e. ISO8859-1 on Windows, UTF-8 on recent Linux distros, IIUC MacRoman on Macs...  Since you got an encoding exception, it's likely that it was defaulting to UTF-8—since it's a fairly rigid scheme—and the file was some other encoding (most likely ISO8859-1).

Broadly, there's no way to tell *a priori* what character encoding was used to generate some bitstream—you need some out-of-band mechanism to communicate it.  In the case of HTTP responses, you can often get it from the `Content-Type` header, but various web apps do it wrong sometimes.  If the file is XML, it's common to claim an encoding in the Processing Instruction at the top.  Some file formats specify a single standard encoding... It's all over the map really.

Your best bet, in the absence of any integration requirement, is to use UTF-8 explicitly everywhere, and don't rely on the platform default encoding.

Comment: I had an issue trying to get google.com even explicitly using UTF-8.